# Disputed flag messages

Tags: support, flagging

Some of my disputed flag messages are—putting it mildly—a little difficult to interpret.

For example:

> I can get you a toe, believe me. There are ways, Dude

Apart from the rather surreally poetic quality of this message<sup>1</sup>, is there any point to this? Should these messages be meaningful in any way or are they simply there for our entertainment?

<sup>1. Actually, I feel a lot like [Jeffrey Beaumont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Velvet_%28film%29) reading this...</sup>

Comment: I don't know if this will _help_, exactly, but: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csvWXwYjtpQ

Comment: Classic - cheers Matt.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

...oops. So, last week [Community](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/-1) went a little insane and started [flagging perfectly fine posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155471/community-is-flagging-good-posts-with-low-answer-quality-score-1), a lot. It's fixed now, but it took a few days. I got tired of just rejecting all the flags as invalid, so for a while I rejected with reasons like:

[image: DIE IN A FIRE, COMMUNITY. I KNOW WHERE YOU SLEEP]

That got boring, so then I started rejecting with lines from The Big Lebowski, on the assumption that nobody would actually see them -- for flags visible to users I try to keep the insanity to a minimum. Unbeknownst to me, apparently people who have counterflagged the post also see the flag rejection reasons, and you had for two of them, so they show up in your history

In short, that wasn't meant for you, it was meant to terrify Community so it would stop messing around. Which it [has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155481), so I'd call those flag rejections a success

Comment: I wholeheartedly approve your manner of responding to Community

Comment: Heh. Outed. I got that it was a BL quote (hence the BV reference), I just wasn't sure what it was meant to convey... It did brighten my day, FWIW :)